# Entity Framework Infinite Self Referencing Entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

i have 3 table and 3 entity class and table names are Roles,Acls,AclsInRole.

Role entity class has relation with AclsInRole entity

```
public class RoleEntity : IdentityRole<Guid>, IEntity
{
public virtual ICollection<AclInRoleEntity> AclRelations { get; } = new List<AclInRoleEntity>();
}
```

and Acl entiy has relation with AclsInRole entity

```
public class AclEntity : BaseEntity
{
  public virtual ICollection<AclInRoleEntity> RoleRelations { get; } = new List<AclInRoleEntity>();
}
```

and

```
public class AclInRoleEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        #region Core Properties

        public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual RoleEntity Role { get; set; }

        public Guid AclId { get; set; }

        public virtual AclEntity Acl { get; set; }

        #endregion Core Properties
    }
```

i run code block in the below .this code return the recursive object .
for example : RoleEntity -> AclInRoleEntity-> AclEntity  -> AclInRoleEntity -> RoleEntity -> AclInRoleEntity -> AclEntity   -> AclInRoleEntity -> RoleEntity -> ......

```
 RoleEntity entity = this._unitOfWork.GetRepository<RoleEntity>().GetFirstOrDefault(
                role => role.Id == new Guid("6FE68340-933C-4F94-64FA-08D68EBA5E79") && role.IsActive, null,
                roles => roles.Include(role => role.AclRelations).ThenInclude(aclRel => aclRel.Acl));
```

can you help me ? How can solve recursive problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite self referencing loop you are facing is called `proxy creation` while using Eager Loading/Lazy loading in EF/EF Core. You cannot stop this proxy creation while using Eager Loading in EF/EF Core. This is the default behavior of EF/EF core and no way to change this.

But may be (I didn't try out) you can stop the proxy creation for Lazy Loading in EF Core >=2.1 as [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading-without-proxies) said.

But you can stop Self referencing loop due to the proxies while you converting the entity to JSON as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

For more details: [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)