# Entity Framework Include Has Infinite References

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've reviewed many solutions for entity framework Include() and can't find a solution that is working. When I use context.A.Include(x => x.B); it contains infinite references of the parent and child objects. I want to disable this. In other words, A -> B and B -> A and A -> B, etc etc. It's causing timeouts and performance issues. How do I avoid this? Using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: You need it for serialization?

Comment: I'm using an MVC setup to retrieve a table and all of it's foreign key references for user management in a site. But the data returning from the API should only have a parent and child object. Not all of the additional parent/child references being nested infinitely.

Comment: Check this [Entity Framework Infinite Self Referencing Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623498/5446495)

Comment: Someone should venmo you $$$$$$. Thanks! ♥

Comment: Just for reference for anyone else stuck on this:
Package - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
Dotnet version - 3.1
Code in Startup - services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

Comment: Another link https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517316/5446495

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
              Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
}
```